# Get running instance of excel with xl.get.excel()

Tags: r

I have one instance of excel running. This contains data I will then read into R (using RStudio). I run

```
xls <- xl.get.excel()
```

but instead of getting the current excel instance that is already running, it opens up a new workbook. I have installed required package `excel.link` and loaded the library. My excel file is also in my working directory. Can you help me figure out why not getting running instance? Thanks!

Comment: Opening a new workbook isn't the same thing as opening a new instance. Are you sure that there are two instances of Excel running after you run that line?

Comment: Hi - yes the new workbook opened in a new instance. BUT I have simply re-started my PC and seems to have solved the problem. Maybe I had an excel process still running in background even though I had closed it.